# Grouping Form Zend not posting Data of Second Form?

Tags: zend-framework

I have 2 Forms, which I am usingain another form to try and keep things DRY.

In this manner:

```
#Forms/my_form.php
$this->addSubForm(new Form_thisForm(), 'this form');
$this->addSubForm(new Form_thatForm(), 'that form');

//then i add 2 more elements a sort and order element
//then a submit
```

So in the view where the form is used, all the fields show from all forms included.
However when posting the form data only the fields from `Form_thisForm()` and the `Form_myForm()`, ie. the main form, are posting. Data or form element names are not posting from `Form_thatForm()`.

The post only contains variables in the 1st subform and full form. Not the second subform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your `Form_thisForm` and `Form_thatForm` are inherited from `Zend_Form`, so they also have `Form` decorator (which basically wraps your subforms in `<form>` tag). 
As a result you have nested `<form>` tags in your html and this is not valid.

You should inherit your subforms classes from `Zend_Form_SubForm` - it has no `Form` decorator by default.